# Advent of Code 2017 Day 6 (part 1) in Functional Programming (FP)

Tags: javascript, programming-challenge, functional-programming, ecmascript-6

I wanted to practice functional programming (FP) without using any library but using vanilla JS only. So I took a problem from Advent of Code (the 1st part of Day 6):

http://adventofcode.com/2017/day/6

> A debugger program here is having an issue: it is trying to repair a
>   memory reallocation routine, but it keeps getting stuck in an infinite
>   loop.
>
> In this area, there are sixteen memory banks; each memory bank can
>   hold any number of blocks. The goal of the reallocation routine is to
>   balance the blocks between the memory banks.
>
> The reallocation routine operates in cycles. In each cycle, it finds
>   the memory bank with the most blocks (ties won by the lowest-numbered
>   memory bank) and redistributes those blocks among the banks. To do
>   this, it removes all of the blocks from the selected bank, then moves
>   to the next (by index) memory bank and inserts one of the blocks. It
>   continues doing this until it runs out of blocks; if it reaches the
>   last memory bank, it wraps around to the first one.
>
> The debugger would like to know how many redistributions can be done
>   before a blocks-in-banks configuration is produced that has been seen
>   before.
>
> For example, imagine a scenario with only four memory banks:
>
> - The banks start with `0, 2, 7, and 0` blocks. The third bank has the most blocks, so it is chosen for redistribution.
> - Starting with the next bank (the fourth bank) and then continuing to the first bank, the second bank, and so on, the 7 blocks are spread
>     out over the memory banks. The fourth, first, and second banks get two
>     blocks each, and the third bank gets one back. The final result looks
>     like this: `2 4 1 2`.
> - Next, the second bank is chosen because it contains the most blocks (four). Because there are four memory banks, each gets one block. The
>     result is: `3 1 2 3`.
> - Now, there is a tie between the first and fourth memory banks, both of which have three blocks. The first bank wins the tie, and its three
>     blocks are distributed evenly over the other three banks, leaving it
>     with none: `0 2 3 4`.
> - The fourth bank is chosen, and its four blocks are distributed such that each of the four banks receives one: `1 3 4 1`.
> - The third bank is chosen, and the same thing happens: `2 4 1 2`.
>
> At this point, we've reached a state we've seen before: `2 4 1 2` was
>   already seen. The infinite loop is detected after the fifth block
>   redistribution cycle, and so the answer in this example is `5`.
>
> Given the initial block counts in your puzzle input, how many
>   redistribution cycles must be completed before a configuration is
>   produced that has been seen before?
>
> Your Input: `2    8   8   5   4   2   3   1   5   5   1   2   15  13  5   14`

My solution in FP:

```js
const banks = `2\t8\t8\t5\t4\t2\t3\t1\t5\t5\t1\t2\t15\t13\t5\t14`;

const parse = input => input
  .split('\t')
  .map(c => parseInt(c));

const copy = input => input.slice();

const isUnique = toCheck => state => toCheck.toString() !== state.toString();

const INPUT = parse(banks);

const redistribute = (input, index, toBeDistributed) => {
  if (!toBeDistributed) return input;
  const nextIndex = index + 1;
  const nextInput = input;
  ++nextInput[nextIndex % input.length];
  return redistribute(nextInput, nextIndex, --toBeDistributed);
};

const solveDaySix = input => {
  let banks = copy(input);
  const states = [input];
  let cycle = 0;
  while (true) {
    ++cycle;
    const max = Math.max(...banks);
    const index = banks.indexOf(max);
    banks[index] = 0;
    banks = copy(redistribute(banks, index, max));
    const stateIsUnique = isUnique(banks);

    if (!states.every(stateIsUnique)) break;
    states.push(copy(banks));
  }
  return cycle;
};

console.log("solution ", solveDaySix(INPUT));
```

Do you think my solution is consistent with the idea of FP (I used loops and mutate variables *inside* my functions)? Is there a better way to write the solution in FP? Any other improvement suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Are you after a "truly" functional approach, or just using more functional features of modern JavaScript? For the first you could draw inspiration from solutions in other "purely" functional languages like [Clojure](https://github.com/borkdude/aoc2017/blob/master/src/day06.clj), [F#](https://github.com/CameronAavik/AdventOfCode2017/blob/master/Program.fs#L119), and others.

Comment: @Jeroen do you think my solution is a practical approach? How would a "truly" FP solution look like? The thing is I want to use JS only in order to solve this. So, I don't want to rely on FP-libraries.

Comment: @Jeroen I was implementing a "truly" FP (or at least what I thought to be "truly" FP). But it seems like not to be practical and got too many downside. See a comparison between my "truly" FP vs. my "procdural" approach: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/185111/advent-of-code-2017-day-5-part-2-in-functional-programming-fp?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: does your code work correct? I get allways `1` as result..

Comment: Yes. The reason why you are getting `1` is because the inital values for `banks` doesn't have `\t` (tabs) anymore, but instead spaces between them. Probably re-formatting issue of SO. Try this input for banks: "const banks = `2 8 8 5 4 2 3 1 5 5 1 2 15 13 5 14`;" If this still doesn't work, then manually put tabs between the numbers. Then it should also work for you. So, this is not a code issue but an input formatting issue. @Roman

Comment: Can you please provide a better title? To me the current one is meaningless and breaks this site's convention. **The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code.** Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](https://CodeReview.meta.StackExchange.com/a/2438/41243) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Explanation

### Algorithm

First we have to break down witch steps we have to do:

1. split bank string to an array
2. change all string values to a number
3. reallocate

#### reallocationRoutine

The algorithm above would look like this in JavaScript:

```
const reallocationRoutine = pipe (
    split (' '),                    // split number by space
    map (Number),                   // cast String to a number
    reallocation ([]) (0)           // reallocate with initial values
)

reallocationRoutine ('0 2 7 0')     // will return 5
```

Pipe is a kind of [function composition](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-function-composition-20dfb109a1a0).

#### reallocation

> I used loops and mutate variables inside my functions

You can avoid muting loops and variables by writing recursive functions. The cool thing about recursive functions is that the logic can be broken down into small steps:

- we need the first index of the biggest number
- we need the biggest number itself
- if our store (`memoryBanks`) includes the current state (`input`)

  - we return the current `cycleCount`
- else we call `reallocation` again, but there for we need to:

  - update the `memoryBanks` with the current `input`
  - `increment` the `cycleCount`
  - and `redistribute` the `input`

So it can looks like:

```
const reallocation = memoryBanks => cycleCount => input => {
    const firstIndexOfMax = input.indexOf(Math.max(...input))
    const max = input[firstIndexOfMax]
    return contains(memoryBanks, input)
        ? cycleCount
        : reallocation
            ( memoryBanks.concat ([input]) )
            ( increment (cycleCount) )
            ( redistribute (input) (firstIndexOfMax) (max) )
}
```

I used the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) for conditions. [The reason why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19849363/8339141) is much more than only because it is shorter.
A `if` should always have an `else` and the ternary operator forces you to.

#### redistribute

Instead of putting the entire logic in `redistribute`, I wrote a function called`loop` that traverses an array for a certain number of steps (`steps`) and a function (`fn`) on the current index of the passed array (`xs`) for each step. So we can create a more generic solution - one of the main ideas of FP.

```
const loop = fn => xs => index => steps =>
    steps <= 0
        ? xs
        : loop
            ( fn )
            ( changeArrayValueOnIndex(index, fn(xs[index]), xs) )
            ( getNextIndex(xs, index) )
            ( steps - 1 )
```

`redistribute` is a special form of `loop` where we `increment` each index we reaches and modify the passed input `xs` so, that the start value gets set to `0`

```
const redistribute = xs => index =>
    loop (increment) (changeArrayValueOnIndex(index, 0, xs)) (getNextIndex(xs, index))
```

## Working Example

Overall, the code is *longer* than the imperative solution, but only because I've encapsulated a lot of logic into its own function like `increment` and `loop`. However, these are now functions that we could *reuse* in our next project and, in addition, we can *test everything* much easier :)

```js
// helper functions
const pipe = (...fns) => fns.reduce((f, g) => (...args) => g(f(...args)))

const map = fn => arr =>
    arr.map(fn)
    
const split = delimiter => str =>
    str.split(delimiter)
    
const arrayIsEqual = ys => xs =>
    xs.length === ys.length
        ? xs.every((x, index ) => ys[index] === x)
        : false

const contains = (xss, ys) =>
    xss
      .map(arrayIsEqual(ys))
      .some(bool => bool)
    
const getNextIndex = (arr, index) =>
    arr[index + 1] != undefined ? index + 1 : 0
    
const increment = x =>
    x + 1
    
const changeArrayValueOnIndex = (index, value, array) =>
    [].concat(array.slice(0, index), value, array.slice(index + 1))
    
    
// functions for businesslogic    
const loop = fn => xs => index => steps =>
    steps <= 0
        ? xs
        : loop
            ( fn )
            ( changeArrayValueOnIndex(index, fn(xs[index]), xs) )
            ( getNextIndex(xs, index) )
            ( steps - 1 )

const redistribute = xs => index =>
    loop (increment) (changeArrayValueOnIndex(index, 0, xs)) (getNextIndex(xs, index))

const reallocation = memoryBanks => cycleCount => input => {
  const firstIndexOfMax = input.indexOf(Math.max(...input))
  const max = input[firstIndexOfMax]
  return contains(memoryBanks, input)
    ? cycleCount
    : reallocation
        ( memoryBanks.concat([input]) )
        ( increment(cycleCount) )
        ( redistribute (input)(firstIndexOfMax)(max) )
}

const reallocationRoutine = pipe(
    split (' '),
    map (Number),
    reallocation ([]) (0)
)

console.log('0 2 7 0:', reallocationRoutine('0 2 7 0'))
console.log('2 8 8 5 4 2 3 1 5 5 1 2 15 13 5 14:', reallocationRoutine('2 8 8 5 4 2 3 1 5 5 1 2 15 13 5 14'))
```