# Advent of Code 2017 Day 6 (part 2) in Functional Programming (FP)

Tags: javascript, programming-challenge, functional-programming, ecmascript-6

I wanted to practice functional programming (FP) without using any library but using vanilla JS only. So I took a problem from Advent of Code [(the 2nd part of Day 6)](http://adventofcode.com/2017/day/6).

You can only access the 2nd part if you type in the solution for the 1st part: `3156` or look at my [solution for part 1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/185176/advent-of-code-2017-day-6-part-1-in-functional-programming-fp).

> --- Part Two --- Out of curiosity, the debugger would also like to know the size of the loop: starting from a state that has already been
>   seen, how many block redistribution cycles must be performed before
>   that same state is seen again?
>
> In the example above, `2 4 1 2` is seen again after four cycles, and
>   so the answer in that example would be 4.
>
> How many cycles are in the infinite loop that arises from the
>   configuration in your puzzle input?

This is my FP solution:

```
/*jshint esversion: 6*/

const banks = `2    8   8   5   4   2   3   1   5   5   1   2   15  13  5   14`;
const parse = input => input
  .split('\t')
  .map(c => parseInt(c));
const copy = input => input.slice();

const INPUT = parse(banks);
const redistribute = (input, index, toBeDistributed) => {
  if (!toBeDistributed) return input;
  const nextIndex = index + 1;
  const nextInput = input;
  ++nextInput[nextIndex % input.length];
  return redistribute(nextInput, nextIndex, --toBeDistributed);
};
const isUnique = toCheck => state => toCheck.toString() !== state.toString();

const solveDaySix = input => {
  let banks = copy(input);
  const states = [input];
  let cycle = 0;
  let foundState = [];
  while (true) {
    ++cycle;
    const max = Math.max(...banks);
    const index = banks.indexOf(max);
    banks[index] = 0;
    banks = copy(redistribute(banks, index, max));
    const stateIsUnique = isUnique(banks);

    if (!states.every(stateIsUnique)) {
      foundState = copy(banks);
      break;
    }
    states.push(copy(banks));
  }
  cycle = 0;
  while (true) {
    ++cycle;
    const max = Math.max(...banks);
    const index = banks.indexOf(max);
    banks[index] = 0;
    banks = copy(redistribute(banks, index, max));
    const stateIsUnique = isUnique(banks);

    if (banks.toString() === foundState.toString()) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return cycle;
};

console.log("solution ", solveDaySix(INPUT));
```

I got 2 while loops that are nearly identical. Is there a way to refactor them? I tried to refactor them into one function. But that function takes and returns 4 parameters:

```
/*jshint esversion: 6*/

const banks = `2    8   8   5   4   2   3   1   5   5   1   2   15  13  5   14`;
const parse = input => input
  .split('\t')
  .map(c => parseInt(c));
const copy = input => input.slice();

const INPUT = parse(banks);
const redistribute = (input, index, toBeDistributed) => {
  if (!toBeDistributed) return input;
  const nextIndex = index + 1;
  const nextInput = input;
  ++nextInput[nextIndex % input.length];
  return redistribute(nextInput, nextIndex, --toBeDistributed);
};
const isUnique = toCheck => state => toCheck.toString() !== state.toString();
const getCycle = (banks, states, foundState, condition) => {
  let cycle = 0;
  while(true) {
    ++cycle;
    const max = Math.max(...banks);
    const index = banks.indexOf(max);
    banks[index] = 0;
    banks = copy(redistribute(banks, index, max));
    const stateIsUnique = isUnique(banks);
    if (condition(states, foundState, banks)) {
      foundState = copy(banks);
      return { banks, states, cycle, foundState };
    }
    states.push(copy(banks));
  }
};

const solveDaySix = input => {
  let banks = copy(input);
  let states = [input];
  let cycle = 0;
  let foundState = [];

  let {banks: nextBanks, states: nextStates, foundState: nextFoundState } = getCycle(banks, states, [], (s, f, b) => !s.every(isUnique(b)));

  let {cycle: secondCycle} = getCycle(nextBanks, nextStates, nextFoundState, (states, nextFoundState, b) => b.toString() === nextFoundState.toString());
  return secondCycle;
};

console.log("solution ", solveDaySix(INPUT));
```

Even though it works, I have a hunch that there is a more elegant way.